# how to connect to Microsoft Sql Server 2000, sql server 2005, sql server 2008 and sql server 2012 using the sqlcmd from the same machine?

Tags: sql-server, remote-access, sqlcmd, sql-server-native-client

I need to connect to different sql server databases through python script. I'm trying to use the sqlcmd or sql native client to connect to all these databases.I've installed the native client for sql 2005 and 2008 but all I'm seeing is sql native client 11.0.

I'm using this command to connect to database but I'm getting this error.

cmd -

```
sqlcmd -U 'sa' -P <password> -S <IP_address>
```

error-

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login failed for user '
'sa''..
```

With the same username and password I'm able to connect to the db on the remote machine through management studio.

I'm not sure what is the error. Do I need to configure the server for some setting or something else.

I'm able to connect to sql server using the management studio from remote machine with the same username/password.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of using the single quotes instead of double quotes. this string will work if the parameters are given in "double quotes".

Answer (score 0):

cmd -->
sqlcmd -U 'sa' -P  -S Servername